# find value that occurs for every server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I measure once an hour the sizes of all my databases in all my servers.
This information is stored in a simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DB_Sizes](
    [DB_sizes_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Server] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Time_of_measurement] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Databasenaam] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [DataFileSizeMB] [int] NULL,
    [LogFileSizeMB] [int] NULL)
```

The date that is stored in `Time_of_measurement` is rounded to hours: eg `2014-03-25 13:00:00.000`

The problem is that not each server is measured at the same moment. So I could have for example:

```
server1 2014-03-25 09:00:00.000
server1 2014-03-25 10:00:00.000
server1 2014-03-25 11:00:00.000
server2 2014-03-25 09:00:00.000
server2 2014-03-25 10:00:00.000
server2 2014-03-25 13:00:00.000
server3 2014-03-25 08:00:00.000
server3 2014-03-25 09:00:00.000
server3 2014-03-25 10:00:00.000
server3 2014-03-25 13:00:00.000
```

As you see, server1 hasn't been measured yet for 2014-03-25 13:00:00.000. On other days, it might be server3 that is not measured yet. Tomorrow it might be server2 that is lagging behind.
Now I am looking for the most **recent** measurement that 'occurs for **every** server'.
It is guaranteed that there will be moments that all servers are measured within the same hour, thus having the same value for Time_of_measurement
In the example above the wanted value was `2014-03-25 10:00:00.000`
The number of servers can differ, now there are 3, it will run up to 10+ servers.
So simply outer joining the table with itself for each server is not a viable solution.

Suggestions? Plz?

Comment: In should be something along the lines of  `SELECT Server, MAX(Time_of_measurement) FROM table GROUP BY Server`. I am not expert on tsql and sql server, that is why I am posting this as a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd view every set of times returned by a server as a separate data set. Gather those sets and use the INTERSECT operation.

Using your test data:

```
CREATE TABLE #server1 (measurement datetime NOT NULL)
CREATE TABLE #server2 (measurement datetime NOT NULL)
CREATE TABLE #server3 (measurement datetime NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO #server1 VALUES ('2014-03-25 09:00:00.000'), ('2014-03-25 10:00:00.000'), ('2014-03-25 11:00:00.000')
INSERT INTO #server2 VALUES ('2014-03-25 09:00:00.000'), ('2014-03-25 10:00:00.000'), ('2014-03-25 13:00:00.000')
INSERT INTO #server3 VALUES ('2014-03-25 08:00:00.000'), ('2014-03-25 09:00:00.000'), ('2014-03-25 10:00:00.000'), ('2014-03-25 13:00:00.000')

SELECT MAX(measurement)
FROM (
  SELECT measurement from #server1
  INTERSECT
  SELECT measurement from #server2
  INTERSECT
  SELECT measurement from #server3
) as a
```

This returns '2014-03-25 10:00:00'.

Comment: KISS! (Keep It Simple Stupid) Thank you! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well, you want the most recent time for each server, if it's correct you can run this query

```
Select Server, max([Time_of_measurement]) mostRecentMeasurement From [dbo].[DB_Sizes]
group by Server
```

Comment: That gives me the most recent time PER SERVER while I am looking for the most recent time that is valid for each server

Comment: Can you write us the desired result (the result of query)

Comment: <quote> In the example above the wanted value was 2014-03-25 10:00:00.000 <unquote> The solution by user849924 fitted the bill exactly but thanks for thinking with me!